# Print values from array

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I print the values from my array on one line, separated by a space?

I also want to put the cursor on the next line, once printed.

This is my method I have to use:

```
public static void println(int[] seq){
```

For example:

```
println(new int[]{1, 2}) → 1 2
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
public static void println(int[] seq) { 
    int x = {seq}; 
    int[] x; 
    x = new int[seq]; 
    System.out.println(x[seq]);
}
```

Comment: can you also add an actual question? and what you tried. not just your assignment

Comment: What do you mean by *Cursor?*

Comment: the text pointer should atomatically start on the next line

Comment: You are asking how to create `println(int[])` that should print every number on one line separated by spaces and then add a "nextLine" character. But what have you tried ? This is a really simple task to do ... Edit your question with a question and of course what you have tried because I don't see what would be the problem to create the method.

Comment: im new at this so i really need all the help i can get pls ,what are the terms to use for this thing? can i see the code maybe ill understand it better.

Comment: But what have your tried ? I am not going to do it for you ... SO is not here to give you the code but to guide you. See [ask]

Comment: public static void println(int[] seq) {
     int x = {seq};
  int[] x; 
  x = new int[seq];
  
  System.out.println(x[seq]);  i did this

Comment: You have two variable called `x`, I don't see what you tried with `int x = {seq};` ... You don't loop on `seq` to print what you want.

Comment: public static void println(int[] seq) {
  int[] array = new int[]{};
  
  System.out.println(array); now i have this

Comment: Why are you using `array`, you receive the array in parameter. Iterate `seq` and `print(seq[i])` then add new line. You should start following tutorials because I can't teach you everything about programming.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all the assignments you're attempting in your method.

You can print the numbers in a few ways, two of which are below:

```
public static void println(int[] seq) {
        //this will print them as an array, i.e. [1, 2, 3]
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(seq));
        //and print a new line 
        System.out.print("\n");

        //alternatively, if you just want to print the characters
        for (int i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(seq[i] + " ");
        }
    }
```

You just need to call the `println` method and pass in the `int[] array` you require.

Answer (score 0):

Use for each loop to print values of array.

```
public static void println(int[] seq) { 
    for(Integer value: seq){
      System.out.println(value);
   }
}
```